# Unity как пользоваться DontDestroyOnLoad для использования переменных в другом скрипте

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-mirror

Есть 2 скрипта, в одном я объявляю `gameobject` и присваиваю ему значение `setactive false`, в другом же скрипте, при определенном действие, мне надо, чтобы `set active` стал `true`.
Вот что написал я, ошибок не показывает но и объект не появляется

1. Скрипт, где я объявляю `gameobject`:

   ```cs
   public GameObject win;
   public GameObject moneyPrefab;

   public void Start()
   {
       win.SetActive(false);
       dead.SetActive(false);
   }

   void Awake()
   {
       DontDestroyOnLoad(win);
       DontDestroyOnLoad(dead);
   }
   ```
2. Скрипт второй, где пытаюсь поменять `setactive` на `true`.

   ```cs
   static GameManager dead;
   static GameManager win;

   private void Start()
   {
       win = gameObject.AddComponent<GameManager>();
       dead = gameObject.AddComponent<GameManager>();
   }

   [ClientRpc]
   public void RpcDead()
   {
       dead.gameObject.SetActive(true);
       manager.deadMoneyText.text = "Вы заработали: " + money;
       Debug.Log("dead");
   }

   public void Rpcwin()
   {
       win.gameObject.SetActive(true);
       manager.winMoneyText.text = "Вы заработали: " + money;
       Debug.Log("win");
   }
   ```

Что надо изменить что бы все заработало?